# AWS EC2 instance connection refused on port 8085

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, server, port

I have a new EC2 instance in AWS where I'm hosting a webpage too. i associated the instance to a security group, and some rules work (like connect to mysql or vesta). I have created a simple server with nodeJS and I want to listen a request from port 8085 (I could choose any....). I have create a inbound rule in the security group to listen to port 8085, and it seems it wants to listen, but the connection is refused: As it is refused, I don't think it is security group problem.

[image]

This is inbound security rules:

[image]
[image]

I tried as other post mention "netstat -a -n | grep 8085" and "netstat -an | grep 8085" but I get nothing
[image]
"

I even disable firewall just in case
[image]

This is my code to create the server

```
    const express = require('express');

    const app = express();
    
    const PORT = 8085;
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send("testing");
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running at: http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
    });
```

When I run it I get the "Server running at http://localhost:8085/" in the console, but as when I type the IP address:8085 in the browser I get The site can't be reached. (port is not listening)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you login to the instance and try to connect to `localhost:8085`, does it work? (eg `curl localhost:8085`)

Comment: When I run localhost:8085 from the console in my instance I get "Failed to connect to localhost port 8085: Connection refused"

Comment: That suggests that either nothing is running on that port, or something _within the instance_ is blocking access. The problem would not be related to anything 'outside' the instance such as Security Groups. Try to get it working first via `localhost:8085`, then try to get it working external to the instance.

Comment: When I type in the console [curl localhost:8085] or [curl localhost:80] or any other port, including the ports that are working, always receive the same response: [curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not much of a telnet guy, so maybe I'm missing something.
You do have a connection to the machine otherwise you would get a timeout error, so your security group is ok.
But notice that you are listening for http requests. As I said before I'm not a telnet guy but I don't think that you are using http protocol in the terminal, as @EdsonCSouza mentioned. Try using curl and see what you get.

Comment: I still don't fully understand, but you are right. From the console, with telnet I get port refused and with netstat I don't see port 8085 listening, but If i type in the browser the address with http instead of https it works!

Comment: Http is a protocol working over TCP, it's in the application level on the OSI model. once you send data with http protocol the http encode it and pass it to the Presentation layer and so on. once it get to the server, the server decode it back with the http protocol rules. since the message wasn't in http to begin with it failed to decode it and raised an error. as the guy above me wrote, you should use curl and it will work.

Comment: but when I use `curl localhost:8085` in the console, I get the message connection refused

Comment: What about `curl http://localhost:8085` curl will try to guess the protocol from the `dns:port` it might not guess it as http. BTW did you check if any other software is using this port?

Comment: `curl http://localhost:8085` , `curl http://localhost`  or `curl localhost` also give me a `(7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8085 (or 443 in the case of just localhost): Connection refused`. However, when I type in the console `curl primerproyecto.ga` it does work displaying the html.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok.
I tested here, your security groups seem ok too...
Can you check if the node process are running when you check if the port are listening please?
This is not clear from the information you have given.

Comment: The node process is running as I get "Server running at http://localhost:8085/" in the console.  The port is not listening. I know that because when I run telnet 3.16.245.82 8085 I get connection refused. I don't know why the connection is refused and I don't know any alternative.

Comment: what command do you run to start the node process?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that was missing was the firewall in VESTA. I did everything again and it didn't work until i configured it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you also check your VPC's Network Access Control Lists(ACLs)?
There might be an explicit deny that could be blocking this
[Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html)

Comment: That is a good point, but it looks like AWS has it for VPC's. I have a VPS and I don't know if you can enable in AWS a ACL for a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change localhost to the private IP of your ec2 instance if you are trying to connect the instance locally with api gateway or what so ever. That worked for me ..
PS: May be a bit off the track answer but could help someone